# Input on textbox to call a function?

Tags: javascript

I want a JavaScript where a function is called when a user types something in the textbox. For example when the user types

1. "command1" in the text box, the `function1()` will be called
2. "command2" will call `function2()`

and so on.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My code so far:

```
function myFunction() { 
    var command = prompt("enter your command", "/command"); 
    if command("/hello") {
        //call function1 
    } 
} 

function1() { alert("hi") }
```

If you have another way to solve this, it will help too.

Comment: This is quite a basic question - have you looked at the [available events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) that are triggered as a result of keyboard actions?

Comment: Could it be, that you pasted your code in the wrong field while editing the question?

Comment: because im new..idk how you did that
lol

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='textBox1' />
```

JS:

```
    $('#textBox1').keyup(function(){
    switch(this.val()){
        case 'command1':
            this.val(command1());
            break;
        case 'commandB':
            this.val(commandB());
            break;
    }
});

function command1(){return 'command1 was inputted'}
function commandB(){return 'B was inputted'}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/na14h640/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
$('#yourTextbox').keyup(function() {
   var val = $(this).val();

   if(val == "command1") {
      function1();
   }else if(val == "command2") {
      function2();
   }
});
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

let your textbox id is `txt`
so your js Code

```
function function1(){
alert('f1');
}
function function2(){
alert('f2');
}
$('#txt').blur(function() {
    var getText=document.getElementById("txt").value;
    if(getText == "command1"){
               function1();
          }
          if(getText == "command2"){ 
                function2();
          }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/Lcghvypf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs just a few changes:

```
function myFunction() { 
    var command = prompt("enter your command", "/command"); 

    if (command == "/hello") {
        function1 ();
    } 
} 

function function1() {
    alert("hi");
}

myFunction();
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/h7fq3rk7/)

Answer (score 0):

Can i put the Switch thing?
here:

```
function myFunction() {
    var   command;
    command= prompt('Enter your command, hello');
    if (command === null) {
        return; 
    }
    switch (command) {
    case 'hello':
        alert("hello");
        break;
    case 'bye':
        alert("goodbye");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would set an onclick listener on a button and when the user clicks it, it takes the input, and says:

```
<textbox id="textBox"/>
<button onclick="onClickButton();"/>
<script>
    function onClickButton(){
          if(document.getElementById("textBox").value == "command1"){
               command1();
          }
          if(document.getElementById("textBox").value == "command2"){ 
                command2();
          }
     }
</script>
```

Does this help :D